# ItemListener println double output

Tags: java, swing, println, itemlistener

```
jbox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            for (int x = 0; x < string.length; x++) {
                if (jbox.getSelectedItem() == string[x]) {
                    System.out.println(string[x]);
                }}}});
```

When I run this it prints twice.
What have I done wrong? 
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Don't forget to use the search capabilities of this site. For instance [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+itemlistener+twice) will get you helpful results.

Answer (score 2):

The ItemListener will trip twice since one item is deselected and another is selected. Consider using an ActionListener.

Note though that you shouldn't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
if (jbox.getSelectedItem() == string[x]) {
```

do

```
if (jbox.getSelectedItem().equals(string[x])) {
```

Comment: Thank you. It prints normally now.